# Difference between seed, nut, kernel, pit, grain

Tags: differences, synonyms

I was reading on a food package that it contained seeds AND grains. I thought, aren't they the same thing?

I thought for a second and it seems like the following are all the same thing:

```
Seed (as in apple)
Grain (as in wheat)
Nut (as in almond)
Kernel (as in corn)
Pit (as in olive)
Bean (as in fava/broad bean)
```

Aren't they all the same thing - seeds? Are there particular differences in meaning or etymology between them?

Comment: Yes, there are actual differences. What did a dictionary or encyclopedia tell you when you looked them up?

Comment: Peaches and plums also have pits, which look remarkably like almonds, but which are not nuts. That should give you a lead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is a good question but basically they all refer to part or whole of a particular seed. Apples have pips. Bean can be the shelled or unshelled product or the whole plant. Kernel can also mean just the inner soft part of a seed where there is a hard shell. There's also "stone" and others. Grain can refer to the seed or the whole grain food group. All seeds can be further classified and disected to reveal more part names. I really don't understand where your question is going. The terms you mention have related but also specific meanings within biology and otherwise.